# I cannot SSH or Telnet to Windows Server 2012 on VPS

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012, vps, timeout, putty

I just bought a Windows Server 2012 on VPS.I can connect it using remote desktop and setup mongodb and access it.But i cannot seem to telnet or ssh to it using Putty.

Both ports are open and listening.Putty gives me 'Connection timeout error'.

Below are the screenshots

#### Port is open

[image: Port is open]

#### Port is listening

[image: And listening]

Comment: Did you install the telnet server service to the machine?

Comment: yes i did .it was firewall problem.its solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it must be a firewall... could well be Windows firewall.

Try turning it completely off temporarily (if you are happy to!) to test. Run the following from an elevated (run as administrator) cmd prompt:

```
netsh a s a state off
```

If that is a work around that lets you ssh in then you have found the problem, so turn the firewall back on (again from elevated cmd prompt):

```
netsh a s a state on
```

Then you can try opening port 22 inbound using the following (elevated again):

```
netsh a f a r n="Open Port 22" d=in a=allow prot=TCP localp=22
```

That does it for all profiles.

If turning windows firewall off didn't let you ssh in, then still turn the firewall back on (obviously!). But it might be a firewall further upstream, like at your VPS provider's gateway.